# How to control ADBD from an Android activity?

Tags: android, shell, input, adb

By controlling ADBD (the ADB server daemon process), I mean: Configure, Stop and Start the /sbin/adbd process WITHOUT using the ADB itself.

Prelude conducting to this question :

On some rare Android device, touchscreen isn't present (Smart Glasses etc.). But obviously, many application requires it, so emulating input by software is mandatory.

Shortest solution is to use the input command, but in order to use it from an activity, the special permission INJECT_EVENTS is required.

This permission is granted by either making the application a system application, or by signing the application with the firmware key present in the ROM sources.
My target device requires the firmware key only, and I won't be able to get it.

The single hack I can think of at this point, is to make profit that the ADB can use the input command without requiring anything.

Actually, I can confirm this hack can work by trying it manually through ADB by USB :

1/ Open an ADB shell :
PC command : adb shell

2/ Configure the ABDB to switch on TCP Mode :
Inside the adb shell :

```
    setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555;  // Configure
    stop adbd;                          // Restart
    start adbd;
    adb connect localhost:5555;         // Start a client ADB, to the local ADBD server process
```

3/ From the Activity code :

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "sh", "-c", "adb shell \"input tap 100 200;\";" });
```

**To summarize : The Activity can generate input event without privilege by running a rooted command that start an adb shell connected on it's own adbd process through TCP port.**

Problems are : It requires manual ADBD configuration, ADBD restart, and making an ADB client on the device to connect to it.

Not so good solution : I can set persistent ADBD configuration to avoid the reconfiguration + restart, but that implies a huge security hole because anyone on the LAN can have rooted access on the device.

Command through ADB shell is: setprop persist.adb.tcp.port 5555;

---

Android Activity codes that **I wish they worked** are these :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("stop adbd");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start adbd");
Thread.sleep(3000);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb connect localhost:5555");
```

But from what I can see, it doesn't seems to do anything.

I also tried to use reflection on the hidden SystemProperties API :

```
static public String getprop(String key){
    try { Class c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
        try { Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("get", String.class);
            try { return (String) method.invoke(null, key);
            }  catch (IllegalAccessException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            catch (InvocationTargetException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return null;
}

static public void setprop(String key, String value){
    try { Class c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
        try { Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("set", String.class, String.class);
            try { method.invoke(null, key, value);
            }  catch (IllegalAccessException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            catch (InvocationTargetException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

It seems getprop() works as expected, but doing setprop() then getprop() doesn't show any modification. Neither doing setprop() then the shell getprop command.

There's still someone to read this far ! ;)
Thank you for reading, and a huge thanks to anyone willing to find solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39515054/1778421

Comment: @Alex P. - I think you are trying to tell me that indeed, adb shell uses different privilege than regular application. But I don't get any new hint on how to make regular application to use shell privileges.

Comment: You can not without rooting. Otherwise it would have been a huge security hole

Comment: I know that very well, and I am root. Despite being root, INJECT_EVENT permission cannot be granted without signature certificate. That's why I try this hack that uses a remote shell : because the shell does have this permission.

Comment: Whatever you think you know it is not apparent from your actions (or your own description their of) or your code. Your code only shows attempts to run some commands with your app's UID permissions. And that's what I have addressed with my first comment.

Comment: Despite my application doesn't not have INJECT_EVENT permission, I can inject event by controlling a remote shell through ADB, thus using shell UID.
What I am missing is the ability to dynamically set a system property, then restart the adbd daemon, by being root, and with my application UID.

Comment: Please do enlighten me on why you think that the information you just shared is relevant to the problem you are trying to solve (namely being able to run the `setprop` command)

Comment: I was pointing the fact that shell permission can be usurped. You were saying that I couldn't achieve my goal without being root, but despite being root I don't see the right way neither. Is there a permission required to use setprop ? Thank you Alex

Comment: If this is not the missing link http://stackoverflow.com/a/38311449/1778421 then I am done with the guessing game. You talk too much but provide very little relevant information.